# Set IPv6 DNS address to local host using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, dns, ipv6

I'm running a local DNS server on Windows 8.1, and want to create a PowerShell script to automatically switch between this DNS server and the one provided by DHCP.

I figured out that

```
Set-DnsClientServerAddress -InterfaceIndex 3 -ServerAddresses 127.0.0.1 -Validate
```

can be used to set the DNS address to the local host, and that

```
Set-DnsClientServerAddress -InterfaceIndex 3 -ResetServerAddresses
```

resets the values to the DHCP values.

I also want to change the IPv6 address of the DNS server to the local host (::1), but when I try to do this with

```
Set-DnsClientServerAddress -InterfaceIndex 3 -ServerAddresses "::1" -Validate
```

I get the following 'general error', which I cannot trace back to its cause:

```
Set-DnsClientServerAddress : A general error occurred that is not covered by a more specific error code.
At line:1 char:1
+ Set-DnsClientServerAddress -InterfaceIndex 3 -Validate -ServerAddresses "::1"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (MSFT_DNSClientS...stemName = "2"):ROOT/StandardCi...ntServerAddress) [Set
   -DnsClientServerAddress], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MI RESULT 1,Set-DnsClientServerAddress

Set-DnsClientServerAddress : A general error occurred that is not covered by a more specific error code.
At line:1 char:1
+ Set-DnsClientServerAddress -InterfaceIndex 3 -Validate -ServerAddresses "::1"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (MSFT_DNSClientS...temName = "23"):ROOT/StandardCi...ntServerAddress) [Set
   -DnsClientServerAddress], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MI RESULT 1,Set-DnsClientServerAddress
```

Which command must be used to set the IPv6 DNS address to the local host, and why did my current solution produce the error?

Comment: You used `-validate`. Is the DNS server actually responding on `::1`?

Comment: Thank you very much :) It did not, even though I configured it to listen on ::1. Omitting the -Validated for the IPv6 command worked like a charm, though you would expect PowerShell to throw a more readable error, especially since the -Validate option has a clear meaning and is used for other command too :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-Validate` here means to actually try connecting to the specified DNS servers. If they don't respond, this error occurs.

Of course, you *should* have a DNS server running on the specified address if you actually intend to use it...